# subprocess.on("exit", () => {}) not working if hitting control-c manually kill terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have a program like this

```js
const subprocess = spawn("long-running server");

subprocess.on("exit", () => {
  console.log("Exiting....");
});
```

If the `long-running server` completes its task, on `exit` callback will be executed.

However, if I manually hit `control-c` while the `long-running server` still working, the `exit` callback will not be executed.

How can I achieve executing `exit` callback even if the user manually kills terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Try to catch the interrupt signal SIGINT

> The SIGINT signal is sent to a process by its controlling terminal when a user wishes to interrupt the process. This is typically initiated by pressing Ctrl+C, but on some systems, the "delete" character or "break" key can be used. [SIGINT - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT)

```
subprocess.on("SIGINT", () => {
  console.log("Exiting....");
});
```